# Hibernate/JPA bug - Not recognizing some strings in a enum

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, enums

I have an enum in a class, mapped by Hibernate. One of the mapped fields is and enum type which has one of the following values **OK**, **NOK** or **NAP**. **NOK** or **NAP** works as expected, but when the field the class is set to 'OK', Hibernate fails to map and retrieve the value, which is set to null:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class     com.a.b.c.d.Class$Status: OK
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:113)
```

The class has:

```
private Status status;

@JoinColumn(name = "STATUS")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public enum Status {
    OK, NOK, NAP;
}
```

If I change **OK** to **OK2**, it works correctly. **_OK** also works.
As far as i'm concerned 'OK' is not a reserved name (like in this case where the guy [uses **new**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396564/hibernate-enum-mapping-using-annotaions)) as it compiles correctly.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Up 'till now, what I did to solve the problem is to modify the enum and store '**_OK**' in the database instead of '**OK**', as shown above. Not very nice solution, but it works at least.

```
public enum Status {
    _OK("OK"), 
    NOK("NOK"), 
    NAP("NAP");

    private String desc;

    private Status(String desc){
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
}
```

**BUG REPORT:**

A [bug report has been filled](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-6351).

Comment: Your various tests seems well thought out. It seems you've bug! Please report via hibernate's jira including your sample code.

Comment: I just answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419783/enum-mapping-in-hibernate/6434240#6434240

Comment: @telm, I'm using **Hibernate 3.4.0.GA** and that might be the problem. But, I need to be cautious if I want to upgrade to 3.5.6 or (3.6.5, the lasted final) because that's set on a Maven pom.xml which is used in many products. So, I would have to run some tests before that. But thanks for the advice. I might do as @Bohemian told and fill a bug request.

Comment: FWIW I tried your example with DataNucleus JPA, objects persisted fine with all values, and all read back in ok.

Comment: @telm, @DataNucleus, same problem with 3.6.5.Final. I think the problem is in hibernate-annotations which didn't change from 3.4.0.GA when I changed the hibernate version on the POM.xml. Will try that before reporting.

Answer (score 10):

The problem you have is that in your database you have values others than OK, NOK, NAP and when you are retrieving the records is when you are getting the exception, not when you are persisting.

From your Exception `com.a.b.c.d.Class$Status: OK2` it seems as your database has that value and hence the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class` exception.

Check your table for invalid values, remove/correct them, and try again.

Comment: The database has the OK2 value because I changed from OK to test with the OK2 value in the enum.

Comment: Yes and that is why it fails when you change it back to OK, because the ENUM values does not correspond with the property values. That is exactly what your exception is pointing out. If you fix the values, and get *another* Exception please let me know.

Comment: To rerun all the tests, I've set the the record I'm fetching to 'OK' and all the rest is still _null_. Also, the enum contains 'OK', 'NOK' and 'NAP'.

I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class     com.a.b.c.d.Class$Status: OK
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:113)`

Tried also to set all database records in the table to **status**='OK', so no record has **status**=_null_ anymore, but I got **the same exception** as above.

Comment: Why do you use `@JoinColumn` instead of `@Column`?

Comment: Well, probably a mistake. Corrected that, but the problems persists. Have you seen the updated solution, which is a quick fix but not so nice? Other than that, everything makes me believe it's a bug.

Comment: @lucasarruda You are probably right, it must be a bug. Glad to know that you found an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Thanks, @marcelo-hernandez-rishmawy . I'm trying with a new version and will fill a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

As a another workaround you can try providing an exact column definition to have a VARCHAR column:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(3)")
// @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(3)") // VARCHAR2 for Oracle
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public enum Status {
    OK, NOK, NAP;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having exactly same problem after upgrading HSQLDB from 1.8 to 2.2.6. For enums Hibernate creates columns of type CHARACTER which is a fixed length column (contrary to VARCHAR). The length of it probably determined as a length of the longest enum value. INSERT/UPDATE statements are generated correctly by Hibernate, but when reading values from the table those shorter values come out appended with white spaces.

So, it seems that HSQLDB driver does not trim them. And if it should, I think the bug should be filed for HSQLDB, not Hibernate. However, if this behaviour of HSQLDB is compatible with SQL standard, then it's the Hibernate's EnumType should do trimming when reading enum values.

Comment: thanks for your insight. I filled the bug at Hibernate's Jira in the hope to get a clarification of what that bug might be. I'm considering filling one too at the HSQLDB Bug Tracker, but I might wait for some status change on the first, to go further on the subject.

Comment: Latest HSQLDB is compatible with the SQL standard. CHARACTER(3) means the string is padded with spaces if it's shorter. Several other databases work the same way.

Comment: Well, then is not a bug, @fredt.
Thanks

Comment: @lucasarruda, did you use Hibernate to auto-generate the db schema? I am asking, since if that is Hibernate that has generated the column of a fixed length type then Hibernate should be able to read from that column without a problem, otherwise Hibernate's logic would prove inconsistent, hence containing a bug.

Comment: No, it was created by the DBA. As far as I remember (because I don't work on the place I did that code anymore) the field was defined by VARCHAR(3). And that could be the problem. But if the field where a VARCHAR(x), with x > 3, wouldn't that supposed to work too?

Comment: In case of `VARCHAR(3)` it should work perfectly in your case (as the field length is VARiable, and Status enum values are no longer than 3 CHARacters), though `CHARACTER(3)` gives you values appended with white spaces for values shorter than 3 characters, i.e. `"OK "`.

So the bug filed in Hibernate JIRA seems to be inappropriate. (However, I still think Hibernate should be smart enough to deal with fixed-length columns in such cases. Will leave for the Hibernate devs' consideration.)

Comment: I get it, but I still think the CHAR(3) is more like a hack, because you could actually have A, B, C, K, OK as an EnumType, meaning we have actually CHAR(2). Anyway, Hibernate should cover the case when you don't specify the number of chars, because it works for char > 2 and it should work for char <= 1.