# How to make hibernate 3.5.6-Final and in memory hsqldb 2.0.0 work together?

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, varchar

After upgrading hsqldb dependency in pom.xml from 1.8.x to 2.0.0+ I started getting this error:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: length must be specified in type definition: VARCHAR
```

Obviously, Hibernate generated incorrect CREATE TABLE expression according to HSQLDB 2 requirements. Should I use a different version of Hibernate? Which one? (However, I'd prefer to stick with 3.5.6 for the time being). Or maybe there is a way to use HSQLDB 2 in the back compatible mode?

Thank you.

Comment: My reason for using HSQLDB 2 is that 1.8 does not support extra conditions in JOIN ... ON ... expression. E.g. I need to have a filter on an association like this:

@OneToMany(...)
@Where("type='A'")
Set<Item> items;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you use the latest HSQLDB (2.2.6 at the time or writing) which is on Maven.

You can override the VARCHAR size enforcement using a URL such as

```
jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.enforce_size=false
```

For Hibernate version, better compatibility can be achieved using a more recent version of HSQLDialect.java from Hibernate 3.6.x series. Or just upgrade to the latest 3.6.8

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I have found that the problem was caused by a sql script creating the table, not Hibernate. I fixed the CREATE TABLE statement to specify length of VARCHAR columns - and it worked. Though, that I decided to upgrade Hibernate to 3.6.8.Final and HSQLDB to 2.2.6, however, now am having problem with enums: values are appended with white spaces and Hibernate's EnumType fails when converting a String value to an enum value.

Comment: Use VARCHAR for the column type to avoid space padding. The CHAR type is padded to the lengh used for the definition.

Comment: Yes, that will make it work... but the Hibernate's default behaviour remains wrong, as it fails to read a value saved previously by Hibernate into a column generated by same Hibernate. This particular issue is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8249523/614135

Comment: Also helped me, using HSQLDB 2.3.4. I'm not using Hibernate, so I'm not worried about the problem that @Vlad mentioned. At least, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer on the error

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: length must be specified in type definition: VARCHAR
```

as the error tells us that we are using `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR` in the SQL statement without specifying a length

> so just make sure that you are specifying a length for your column like  `NVARCHAR(255)`

hope this helps you